# Creating a tree, is div or ul better?

Tags: html, tree, html-lists

I am creating my own tree implementation similar to Dojo or jQuery trees (like a file tree, complete with collapsing/expanding nodes) and I am wondering what advantages/disadvantages coding by ul and li tags would have over div tags.  Most implementations that I see (Dojo for example) use divs, but I would think ul and li tags made for representing hierarchical structures would be better suited.  So why the use of divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UL/OL/LI/DIV are all block elements but UL/OL/LI impart more semantic information.

Don't get a case of DIVitus :-) I do not know why others have this syndrome, perhaps there are some legacy iCab issues? *chuckle*

OL often makes "semantic sense" over UL because most trees/lists are, well, ordered.

Happy coding.

Comment: Those are my thoughts as well - which is why I wonder why the good OS coders of Dojo and jQuery would be writing up in divs... I was wondering if anyone had tried uls and left them to develop divs, and if so for what reason.

Comment: I have found one possible reason why - when we look at expanded tree nodes, often the children are indicated by a vertical line that connects them all - more visible than just regular indentation.  If we are using UL/OL/LI then we lose some of the background image offset abilities we get with divs.